# Github Pages: /README.md relative links to other foo/README.md files but breaks if foo/index.html exists

Tags: html, markdown, jekyll, github-pages

My repo, which is also a github-page, has its main README.md with multiple links to README.md's in sub-dirs in the repo:

`[models](./models/README.md)`

The ghpage works nicely. It converts the markdown to html.

But it does *not* work for dirs that *also* have an index.html file! It then simply shows the markdown text, not its html.

And if I rename the index.html file, the problem goes away!

My question is: What is causing this? Maybe a Jekyll issue? Config file setting?
How can I have relative links to .md files work even when an index.html file is present?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer here: https://github.community/t/linking-files-into-folders/115936/2

Specifically, if an index.html and README.md are in the same repo, the index.html wins:

> Your repository contains both a README.md file and an index.html file.
> This presents a conflict, as GitHub Pages is designed to publish both
> files as index.html. Under these circumstances, the index.html file in
> your repository takes precedence, and GitHub Pages skips the process
> of converting your README.md file to HTML.

This makes a lot of sense, but is not well documented, alas. Hope folks find it here.